# Разные отступы у каждой строки

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg

Верстая тренировочный макет, столкнулся с одним странным кейсом

[image: 1]]

Я реализовал подобное ставя &nbsp в нужном количестве, чтобы добавиться такого же результата. 
Существует ли более красивый метод реализации этого?

```
        <div class="section-outer rightline-02">
            <div class="rightline-02__quote">
                    &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspBeauty<br>
                    &nbspis the <br>
                    &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspharmony <br>
                    &nbspof purpose <br>
                    &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<i>&</i> form.
            </div>
            <div class="rightline-02-photo">
                <svg viewBox="0 0 960 980">
                    <path d="M450,0 L900,450 L450,980 L0,450 L450,0 Z"
                    vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
                </svg>
                <div class="rightline-02-photo__img">
                    <img src="img/02.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rightline-02-description"></div>
        </div>
```

```
    &-02{

        display: flex;
        position: relative;
        justify-content: center;

        &-description,
        &-photo{
            flex-basis: 50%;
        }

        &__quote{
            position: absolute;
            font-size: 120px;
            line-height: 1;
            align-self: center;
            text-align: center;
            z-index:15;  
        }

        &-photo{                         
            position: relative;

            background-color: $light-blue;
            display: flex;
            svg{
                flex:1; 
                path{
                    fill-rule: evenodd;
                    stroke: $white;
                    stroke-width: 1px; 
                    stroke-linecap: butt; 
                    stroke-linejoin: miter; 
                    fill: none;
                }
            }
            &__img{
                padding-left: 190px;
                position: absolute;
                img{
                    max-height: 726px;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: существует, через `absolute`, к примеру

Comment: @meine небось поползет на разных экранах?

Comment: @meine разумеется, что был использован absolute чтобы блок с текстом встал поверх других блоков. Я про отступы внутри текста, которые разные на каждой строчке. Каким образом их реализовать без банального добавления пробелов ?

Comment: @Эникейщик, ну, если руки не крюки, то не поползет :)

Comment: сделайте через svg и ничего никуда не поползёт

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Решение SVG

Если всё добавить в блок SVG, то легко можно добиться позиционирования строк, изображения.
 **Вёрстка будет адаптивной и выглядеть одинаково во всех браузерах, включая `IE`**

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1200 1748" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >  
<rect width="70%" height="100%" fill="#E5EAEB" />

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ynrb0.png" y="50" width="600px" height="874px" /> 
<text font-size="72" font-weight="500" fill="black">
  <tspan x="820px" y="300px">Beauty</tspan>
     <tspan x="760px" dy="75px">is the</tspan>
    <tspan x="760px" dy="75px">harmony</tspan>
  <tspan x="680px" dy="75px">of purpose</tspan> 
  <tspan x="780px" dy="75px">&#38; form </tspan>  
 </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: А подскажите, пожалуйста, для чего (и обязательно ли) указывать version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"? Вроде бы, всё работает и без этих атрибутов.

Comment: @humster_spb на enSO была большая дискуссия на эту тему, - Однозначный результат только - `version 1.1` можно точно не указывать. А остальное, указывать всё таки нужно и тогда будет уверенность, что везде будет работать одинаково. Для примера сохраните пример в формате `*.svg` без указания `namespace` или  `w3.org/1999/xlink` и попробуйте запустить его в браузере и сразу получите сообщение об ошибке.

Answer (score 1):

Ничего толкового без разбития строк на элементы всё равно не получится. Но наименьшее количество писанины, на мой взгляд, будет так:

```css
.text{
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight:500;
}
.text span{
  display:block;
}
.text span:first-child{
  text-indent:2em;
}
.text span:nth-child(2),
.text span:nth-child(3){
  text-indent:1em;
}
.text span:nth-child(5){
  text-indent:.75em;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <span>Beauty</span> <span>is the</span> <span>harmony</span> <span>of purpose</span> <span>& form</span>
</div>
```